# Create list [(1,1),(1,2), .. ,(1,n)], for any given n. Use this list then to create all fractions 1.0/k k from 1 to n

Tags: python, python-2.7

completely new to python tried doing this but did not work.

```
>>> list (range (1, 9))

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

>>> args = [1,9]

>>> list (range (args))
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You should read up list comprehension and play around with them a bit

Comment: Wow, didn't read the title and had no idea what these answers were thinking. Somebody should edit the post and throw that in there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create first list:

```
[(1, x) for x in range(1, n + 1)]
```

create second list:

```
[1.0 / x for x in range(1, n + 1)]
```

Comment: but the second calculation doesn't "use" the first list as requested in the title.

Comment: The point is to help people achieve want they want, not to help them walk the way they think is right but is not.

Answer (score 1):

First, the list of `(1,i)` pairs:

```
pairs = [(1, x) for x in range(1, n + 1)]
```

Next, the list of ratios:

```
divs = [num/denom for num, denom in pairs]
```

(you may also need `from __future__ import division` if you're using python 2.x)